# What happens with the things that are outside the skeleton of a category?

Tags: category-theory

I read in Wikipedia that the skeleton of a category is, roughly speaking, the "smallest" equivalent category, which captures all the "categorical properties" of the original.

My questions are: What happens with the objects that are outside, and the morphisms between them? In what sense are they categorically 'redundant'?

Comment: The basic idea is that if $a,b$ are isomorphic objects in a category $\mathcal{C}$, then we don't really need *both* of them; we could "forget" about one without losing any important information. A skeleton is basically a full subcategory gotten by forgetting a maximal amount: we remove *all* redundancies until we're left with no duplication at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber We are losing the morphisms between the forgotten objects. Are they redundant too?

Comment: Remember that the skeleton is a **full** subcategory - so yes, they are equally redundant. E.g. if objects $a$ and $b$ are isomorphic to objects $a'$ and $b'$ in the skeleton, then via isomorphisms $i:a\rightarrow a'$, $j:b\rightarrow b'$ we get a bijection between $Hom(a,b)$ and $Hom(a',b')$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the idea of the skeleton of a category is intimately related to the axiom of choice. That every small category has a skeleton is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

It does not matter which skeleton you pick for a category since skeletons are unique up to isomorphism (though, as pointed out in a comment, not necessarily unique isomorphism). In fact, for every object in a category, there exists a skeleton containing that object. In general, there will be many skeletons.

So nothing "happens" to the objects outside the skeleton of a category (or, to be more precise, outside of a choice of skeleton for a category). There is nothing which distinguishes them from elements of a particular skeleton, except that this particular skeleton doesn't contain them.

In most cases, skeletons of categories aren't terribly useful or helpful since most of category theory is constructive. That said, it is sometimes the case that a category has a simple skeleton (for example, $\mathbb{N}$ with some morphisms is the skeleton of the category of finite sets).

Comment: There is also the notion of "weak skeleton" which is much more natural in my opinion.

Comment: Skeletons are unique up to isomorphism but not necessarily unique isomorphism. If they were unique up to unique isomorphism then there would be functorial skeletonisation.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the comment. You are indeed correct.